# What are the major differences in group-skydiving as opposed to "single" skydiving?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, aerodynamics, drag

Surface area/the cross-sectional area is greatly increased, so my thinking is it *should* decrease terminal velocity as well as a couple of other factors. But mass changes too (since there would be more people attached), so would that, by any chance, cancel out (for lack of a better term) the large surface area's effects?

Comment: If you look at the formula for terminal velocity in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity, you can see that m/A is the relevant factor. Two skydivers with the same m/A ratio will attain the exact same terminal velocity as one unless they manage to modify their combined area, which is easier to decrease, than to increase. Two people holding tight together may be able to fall a little faster than a single person.

Comment: This seems like a really broad question... (edit: or actually it might be just a really broad title for a perfectly fine question)

Answer (score 1):

(been there, done that)

In general, a large, tight formation will fall slower than a small one. But not a lot slower. Body position (drag) makes a larger difference. I can make a very substantial difference to my fall rate with a small change in waist angle - picture it as laying on a beach ball face down vs. face up.

A single jumper can change their fall rate from about 150km/h to 300km/h simply by rotating from flat to head down and tucking everything in - your goggles start to vibrate at those speeds.

> Two skydivers with the same m/A ratio will attain the exact same terminal velocity

Not quite. Induced drag from body position is a major factor. A 50kg girl can easily pass a 120kg fat boy if she knows how.

Comment: Maybe I'm over-thinking things, but any formation with 2+ members will make the entire formation heavier right? So would that not affect the terminal velocity since mg is greater?

Comment: If I'm sitting on your back, yes. But formations are always flat, and the drag effects work over the entire formation like a leaky plate.

Comment: If there are 2 people skydiving, why would one neglect mass as an entire system (say, 50kg + 50kg), but add them together only if they're on top of each other? Sorry I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the "choreography" the skydivers are following: given the terminal velocity formula, it depends, giving the same air/gravity values only by m/A, so if two or more skydivers have similar masses and areas, we get (n*m)/(n*A) which gives again m/A. 
Of course the change of the rotation of any skydiver will affect the terminal velocity of the group.